# Python Read PDF

Tags: python, pdf, jupyter-notebook

I need to read all the tables in a PDF and transform them into a dataframe.
I found this code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
for page in pages:
    
    index = pages.index(page)
    product = product[index]
    print(product)
    
    tl = tb.read_pdf(file, pages=page,area=[box],output_format="dataframe", stream=True)
    
    dft = tl[0]
    dft.rename(columns={ dft.columns[0]: "Fascia d'età", dft.columns[1]: "Casi"}, inplace = True)
    
    region_column = []
    for i in range(0, len(dft)):
        region_column.append(region)
    dft['Regione'] = region_column
    
    df = pd.concat([df, dft])
```

However, `tb.read_pdf()` brings me an error :

```
Error from tabula-java:
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: technology/tabula/CommandLineApp : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
```

Do you know how to overcome this?
Is there any other way to extract the tables of a PDF to a dataframe in Python?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your Java Runtime Environment isn't up to date.
Make sure you're running Java 8, it is a prerequisite for tabula-py.

Comment: Thank you, can you tell me how can I check that information?

Comment: @DanielaRodrigues It depends on your os and java version, funnily enough, check [this link](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/version_manual.html) for info from oracle themselves